# source file appearance validation transfer - SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

My package is depoyed and running file on Dev. However, when I'm trying o run this from test, its showing below error:

> Executed as user: TA\x_dev. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.4000.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  9:50:10 PM  Error: 2016-02-26 21:50:26.83     Code: 0x00000001     Source: Source File Appearance_Validation_Transfer      Description: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.     at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.ShowCore(IWin32Window owner, String text, String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton, MessageBoxOptions options, Boolean showHelp)     at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(String text)     at ST_a3ed049745fb4a87b5abac55eb724bf1.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)     at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  9:50:10 PM  Finished: 9:50:26 PM  Elapsed:  16.521 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Note: This package will run to read XML files and put it in DB.
Also, this package is configured to run from user "TA\x_dev". However, I have re-installed this using another user(x_xxx) and trying to run it through another user(x_xxx).The installation is, "SQL server installation" using package manifest file. Is it something issue related to user?

Could any one please let me understand what this error is ?
How can I get a clue for resolution? Many thanks.

Comment: `Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation.`. Are you trying to display a modal dialog box?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to do anything like this.

Comment: It normally means one of your script components has gone wrong and is trying to pop up an error message. If it's happening on test but not dev, it's likely a permissions problem.

Comment: I have used my question with user information. Could you please update your answer if you think different?

Comment: Search your package code for a `MsgBox` command.   If you find it, remove it and re-deploy.